# 泳いでから and 食べてから

Tags: syntax

I couldn't understand the following sentences:

泳いでから昼ご飯を食べます。

食べてからサッカーをします。

Could you explain me them?

Comment: what do you think they mean and what don't you understand about them?

Comment: Actually I've already got it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -てから form means after (verb).
So, **泳いでから**昼ご飯を食べます means
     **After swimming, I eat dinner**
And, **食べてから**サッカーをします
**After eating,** I play soccer